# How exactly does minimizing the L2 norm of w in SVR affect the model's ability to fit the data?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-foundations, svm

I have a solid grasp on why we minimize the L2 norm of the weight vector ( w ) in Support Vector Machines (SVM) for classification problems — it maximizes the margin between classes and helps the model generalize well to unseen data. However, I'm finding myself lost when trying to understand the analogous concept in Support Vector Regression (SVR).

While I know that minimizing the L2 norm in classification leads to a larger margin, I'm struggling to see the parallel in SVR. I've read that minimizing the L2 norm of w in SVR also contributes to model simplicity and generalization by making the regression function "flatter," but I'm unable to connect the dots on how this translates mathematically and conceptually to better regression performance. I'm looking for a deep, mathematical explanation that can elucidate the underlying mechanics of SVR and the role of minimizing (|w|^2)/2.

To summarize, my main points of confusion are:

How exactly does minimizing the L2 norm of ( w ) in SVR affect the model's ability to fit the data?
What is the mathematical intuition behind the "flatness" of the regression function, and how does this contribute to the model's predictive power?
How does the concept of minimizing the L2 norm relate to the epsilon-insensitive loss used in SVR, and what are the practical implications of this in terms of model performance?
I'm aiming to gain a fundamental understanding of these aspects of SVR, so I would greatly appreciate detailed explanations or references to resources that could help clear up my confusion. Thank you in advance for your insights!

hi if it looks like chatgtp wrote this, cause it did, i struggle to put ideas into words, so i use chatgtp. so yea just wanted you guys to know.